# Django search for child models via foreign key

Tags: django

I have a models.py file that more or less looks like this:

```
class Match(models.Model):
    match_id = models.BigIntegerField()

class Team(models.Model):
    team_id = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    match = models.ForeignKey(
        Match,
        related_name='teams',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    win = models.BooleanField()

class Player(models.Model):
    player_id = models.IntegerField()
    team = models.ForeignKey(
        Team,
        related_name='players'
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

For each match, I want to find the two teams that played, and for each team, I want to find the players that were on the team. This is what I tried so far:

```
match_id = 123456789
match_info = Match_model.objects.get(match_id=match_id)

red_info = Team_model.objects.get(match=match_info, team_id='Red')
blue_info = Team_model.objects.get(match=match_info, team_id='Blue')

red_players = Player_model.objects.filter(team=red_info)
blue_players = Player_model.objects.filter(team=blue_info)
```

but Django is giving me the error:

```
Team matching query does not exist.
```

How would I go about fixing this error? Any pointers on how to correct my queries would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why not just `red_players = red_info.players.all()`?

Comment: Django is telling you the problem - `Team matching query does not exist` must mean that there is a `Match` that does not have either a red or blue team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try:
    red_info = Team_model.objects.get(match=match_info, team_id='Red')
    blue_info = Team_model.objects.get(match=match_info, team_id='Blue')
except Team_model.DoesNotExist:
    pass
else:
    red_players = Player_model.objects.filter(team=red_info)
    blue_players = Player_model.objects.filter(team=blue_info)
```